# No funciona consulta adecuadamente si uso más campos (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta donde estoy validando que NO se repita la misma persona en la BD.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```js
BEGIN
      SELECT P.Id_paciente, P.Nombre_pas, P.Id_sucursal  FROM  persona as P WHERE 
      P.Nombre_pas=Nompas AND P.Segundo_nom=Segnopas AND P.Apellido_pat=Apepatpas
      AND P.Apellido_mat=Apematpas AND P.Fecha_nac=Fechapas AND P.Cel=Celpas
      AND P.Dir=Dirpas AND P.Id_sucursal=Idsucpas;
END
```

Lo que no entiendo, es por que funciona con algunas personas y con otras no. Estoy cuidando que no se pasen espacios vacíos etc... Entonces, no me siento seguro que esto funcione al 100%. Hasta intenté cambiar el orden de la consulta (el orden de los campos en el "WHERE") y tampoco.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o qué está mal?

Gracias y saludos.

Nota: Lo estoy poniendo en un SP.

Cuando uso estos datos que SI funciona solo muestra el ID de la persona encontrada:

```js
BEGIN
          SELECT P.Id_paciente, P.Nombre_pas, P.Id_sucursal  FROM  persona as P WHERE 
          P.Nombre_pas='Agapita' AND P.Segundo_nom='Teófila' AND P.Apellido_pat='Pérez'
          AND P.Apellido_mat='Pérez' AND P.Fecha_nac='2000-02-15' AND P.Cel='3336959987'
          AND P.Dir='Calle del gato loco #123. Colonia del Veterinario.' AND P.Id_sucursal=1;
    END
```

Ahora, cuando uso estos datos de otra persona que SI existe en la BD y la trato de encontrar, pero, no la reconoce y no regresa nada la consulta y por lo tanto daría paso a insertar... Y es lo que no quiero:

```js
BEGIN
              SELECT P.Id_paciente, P.Nombre_pas, P.Id_sucursal  FROM  persona as P WHERE 
              P.Nombre_pas='María' AND P.Segundo_nom='Mercedes' AND P.Apellido_pat='Hernández'
              AND P.Apellido_mat='Martínez' AND P.Fecha_nac='2000-12-24' AND P.Cel='3337898888'
              AND P.Dir='Av. Perico rabioso  y divorciado #456. Colonia del Veterinario #2.' AND                       P.Id_sucursal=1;
END
```

Y por eso me inquieta.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos que salida te da en los casos correctos y cuál es el error?

Comment: Edite la pregunta. No muestra error. Lo que pasa es que no funciona correctamente la consulta en el sentido de que con unas personas SI la encuentra y otras no. Entonces, algo está mal -digo yo- porque no cumple su función al 100% el SP y es lo que quiero saber es el "por que".

Comment: Pueda que sean los acentos. Dependiendo del sistema que sea, yo prefiero tratar los datos de una sola forma y evitar este tipo de cosas. Pero creo que acá falta algo, pueden haber varias personas llamadas igual y nacidas el mismo día, lo que no puede repetirse son los "Identificadores" de estas personas, DNI, Pasaporte... Porque no lo haces bajo ese criterio??